# What is WS-I profile in Web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

What is WS-I profile in Web service ?

Comment: Do you mean WS-I (with an 'i' as in WebService Interoperability) as described here: http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html ?

Comment: Or as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WS-I (Web Services Interoperability) BP-1 (Basic Profile 1) [specification](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html):

> This document defines the WS-I Basic
>   Profile 1.0, consisting of a set of
>   non-proprietary Web services
>   specifications, along with
>   clarifications and amendments to those
>   specifications which promote
>   interoperability.

The basic idea was to look at aspects of the SOAP and WSDL specifications that tend to promote interoperability, and those that do not.